# Node environment variable for App on docker and Queue Service running on pm2

Tags: node.js, docker, queue, pm2, production-environment

I have nodejs app running in a docker container. I have set the node environment in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "server": "nodemon server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "build-client": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run server"
  }
```

The app is running fine.
But when I'm running a service separately using PM2, even though the node environment is set to production, it's not using the production config.

Below is the config import in service

```
const Queue = require("../queue/queue");
const connectDB = require("../../config/db");
const constants = require("../constants");

connectDB();
```

Comment: which docker image is it running on? is the OS same?

Comment: I have 4 docker images
1. node  (12-alpine)
2. mongo
3. redis
4. app

OS is linux Lubuntu

Comment: Okay. Use the "cross-env" library for setting the environment variables

Comment: Thanks @kavigun, I will try and let you know

Comment: Hi @kavigun I used "cross-env" library for setting the environment  variable, but stiill it's not working for me.

Comment: How do you run it with pm2?

Comment: app is on docker, but there's a service (job/worker) with app which is not on running on docker. It is running on pm2.
<<pm2 start services /queue/worker.js>> 
I also did an export NODE_ENV=production